# How to check if message is sent to Slack channel is more than 15 min?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, slack-api

I need to send alert to the slack channel if some application got crashed, I have set up the slack webhooks and it is sending messages to Slack but I need to check -

- if application is crashed and it is been crashed for more than a minute
- if it is then check if the app already been sent to slack channel.
- if it is already been sent then wait for 15 min to send alert again.

```
foreach (var item in data)
{
    if (item.ProcessState == "CRASHED" && DateTime.Now - item.AppUpdatedAt  >= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
    {
        if (DateTime.Now - item.AppUpdatedAt  >= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
        {
            client.PostMessage(username: "Mr. Torgue",
           text: item.AppName + "is CRASHED on" + item.AppFoundation,
           channel: "#general");
        }

    }

}
```

I'm kind of stuck how should I maintain a record of already sent alerts.

Comment: Why not use a professional monitoring service like this one: https://uptimerobot.com/

Comment: it's an internal tool and not exposed to the internet

Comment: well then I would suggest you log sent messages in your app. e.g. by storing a record of sent messages in your DB and checking against it before sending new messages.